# Mocking imports with webpack 2 / karma

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, webpack, karma-runner

I am trying to figure out how to speed up the unit testing on my project. I am using webpack 2 and karma.

I have a custom npm module which I am bundling with my application. This has a lot of exports which have dependencies (using tree shaking in project).

For example index.js of my npm module "Test" looks like this:

```
export Button from "./Button"
export Unused1 from "./Unused1"
export Unused2 from "./Unused2"
...many more imports follow
```

My component tests will use "Button" from "Test"

```
import {Button} from "Test"
```

I want to create a simple test which will be bundled by webpack and fed to karma/phantomjs. The test should only bundle/resolve what is needed, so for example it should only resolve "Button" in the above example.

I have tried mocking "Test" using
https://github.com/plasticine/inject-loader
and
https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire

Basically, I tried injecting "Test" : { Button}, where Button I imported from "Test/Button" in my test file.

They both seem to still bundle the whole index.js of "Test" which includes all the exports.

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use require.context?

```
// webpack.testfiles.js:

var context = require.context('./js', true, /spec\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

then in the karma config pass that file in:

```
...
        files: [
            'webpack.files.js',
        ],
...
```

Read more here: [Webpack Dependency Management](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/)